# How to undo login password removal

Tags: 14.04, login, password

I need help, I am very new to Ubuntu and am running 14.04 LTS. the problem was that my password login screen would prompt me twice for my password, I could not find a solution so I decided to remove my password login completely. I found a web page telling me how to remove it and I succeeded in doing so, but now it prompts me twice for my keyring password.. I have looked for a solution to this but no luck, I have decided just to go back to having my normal password on the login screen and wait for a solution to the double login problem, but apparently I did not bookmark the site I used to remove it and I cannot remember how to undo it..

Any Suggestions?

output of *cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf* in terminal is  *[SeatDefaults]
autologin-user=*

Comment: How did you "remove your login password"? You probably changed setting to login without entering password?

Comment: My guess is that you probably set autologin in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` file. Open that with `sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` and get rid of lines that say anything about autologin = yourusername (forget the exact syntax). Let us know if that worked

Comment: No I tried that first but still received the keyring login prompt so I used the command line to remove my password completely thinking that would work but it still prompts me for my keyring password. so I would like to just try an undo my password removal an go back to logging in twice when I start my computer.  I realize this may difficult to answer seeing as how I do not know what command lines used to remove my password prompt but hoped maybe someone might know.

Comment: Nope I do not show anything in lightdm.conf         @Serg

Comment: Well, if you don't figure it out, just create a new account, chown your old folder to your new username and your new usergroup and delete the old account

Comment: Hmm that is a solution, If you don’t mind me asking how would I do that?

Comment: And I do not quite get the problem. Does `sudo -s` command work? Keyring issue can be solved differently.

Comment: yes sudo -s does work, my problem is when turn on my computer it pops up my account name and a button that says Log In (instead of asking for my password like it used to). I click log in and it brings up my desktop and prompts me for my keyring password.    @Pilot6

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add there output of `cat /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` terminal command.

Answer (score 1):

To get autologin working run in terminal:

```
sudo gedit /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf
```

And in the line

```
autologin-user=
```

add your user name.

To disable keyring password you can use [THIS GUIDE](https://askubuntu.com/a/496047/167850)

**But it is a security issue**

Answer (score 0):

Try using `passwd [new passwd]` from your account? This will create a password. If that does not work, then `sudo passwd -u [new password] [username] definately should`.